# Fluent NHibernate Console App

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I Have the Following Code in a VERY small Console App:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var factory = CreateSessionFactory();
            var session = factory.OpenSession();
            Console.Write("done");
            Console.Read();
        }
        static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            string csStringName = Environment.MachineName;
            var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                              .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(csStringName)))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(StatusCode))))
                .BuildSessionFactory();

            return cfg;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine, following along on example on Tekpub, however when I go to build I loose all the VS colors and I get the following Errors:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'FluentNHibernate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\PROJECTS TEST\test\test\Program.cs   6   7   test
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'FluentNHibernate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\PROJECTS TEST\test\test\Program.cs   7   7   test
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'NHibernate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    C:\PROJECTS TEST\test\test\Program.cs   8   7   test
Error   4   The type or namespace name 'ISessionFactory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\PROJECTS TEST\test\test\Program.cs   21  16  test
```

I find it so strange that this seems not to work but ONLY when inside a Console App as I have it working in another larger project that I am attempting to convert from XML to Fluent.

Any Ideas ?

EDIT the issue seems to be something to do with VS 2010  if I attempt to build this project in 2008 it builds fine. I would still like to know why it would work in one and not the other.

Comment: Do you have your references set?

Comment: ya I do, I think it might have something to do with X86 vs x64 builds? Moved the files to Call Library and it builds but If I try to even reference the project from a Console app it says it cannot find the reference.